# How to design this bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, frontend, flutter-dependencies, bottom-navigation-bar

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any dependency available that can easily design this bottom navigation bar?

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this without any external package of course by using a stack and a couple of containers have a look at the following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 80.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(
                            30.0,
                          ),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(
                            15.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 60.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 3,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 80.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(
                            15.0,
                          ),
                          topRight: Radius.circular(
                            30.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 15.0,
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: 90.0,
                width: 90.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    45.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 25.0,
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: 70.0,
                width: 70.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    35.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 30.0,
            ),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Container(
                height: 60.0,
                width: 60.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                    30.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  CupertinoIcons.home,
                  color: Colors.pink,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2WSR.png)

this is an example of how to do it. If you want to implement the order and notifications buttons and the others, you can split the first container in the Row() into two containers, and by playing a little bit with margins, you can achieve this design very quickly.

remember that there are other thousands of ways to do it, it just depends on how much you know about flutter widgets.

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

check packages
[animated_bottom_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_bottom_navigation_bar) and
[curved_navigation_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/curved_navigation_bar)